# How to use JWPlayer in native android app?

Tags: android, webview, jwplayer

I AM working on some project, I need to use the JWPlayer in my app for running the videos due to some reasons. But I can't find any way to do so, I have implemented the You-Tube player in the past, that worked fine, but now I cant find anything for the JWPlayer for android. I had also refereed the following sites of JWPlayer but it says they had closed the beta version of JWPlayer sdk.

[JWPlayer.com site](http://www.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/)

[JWPlayer.com site Android SDK page](http://www.jwplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/Android-SDK-Overview.pdf)

I had also refereed the following links but could not crack anything from it.

[Stackoverflow link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003433/jwplayer-javascript-api-for-android-webview) In this link the questioner had put a message that he has skipped the project.

[Stackoverflow link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305952/cannot-use-jwplayer-in-an-android-app) This link show the same answer which is not been explained properly, as in the above link by the same person.

Any help would save me my world. And if proper links or guidance is provided it would be a great help to me.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: You should contact us for information about our SDK. http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/

Comment: Update, we now have our SDK for Android. Please see here - http://www.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/

Comment: hey @Ethan JWPlayer, we must put request in contact us for android sdk and later you send android sdk to email? is that how it works?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We will contact you with information regarding it.

Comment: but  @EthanJWPlayer i have few queries like can i use JWPlayer without SDK in android. i mean is there any workaround using **webview**  to implement JWPlayer in android. mean while i have sent request in contact form and have received info like "a sales representative will contact you". But still no further process on that...

Comment: We do not officially support our player inside of a WebView.